# Ajax Controls in Monodevelop

Tags: asp.net-ajax, monodevelop, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'm using Monodevelop(version 3.0.4.6) at Linux (Ubuntu) ,trying to add Ajax control feature in my web application.
Every thing is working good in my web application but when i'm trying to add ajax control ,Monodevelop giving some error like

" System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type 'System.Web.Script.AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute' from assembly 'AjaxControlToolkit'."

Can Some one used Ajax Control in Monodevelop..?

Please Help me !!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [mono implementation status](http://go-mono.com/status/status.aspx?reference=4.0&profile=4.0&assembly=System.Web.Extensions) the AjaxFrameworkAssemblyAttribute is not implemented in mono, so the problem really isn't MonoDevelop but the fact that it isnt implemented in mono. I would assume that you could get the assemblies from a Microsoft .NET implementation and add to your project.